# Dealing with class imbalance

Tags: python, pandas, logistic-regression

I am trying to address the class imbalance in my logistic regression model and my supervisor has left the code down below but I am unsure how to finish off the (amount_0= and the amount_1=) lines.

`amount_0 =`
`amount_1 =`

`total = amount_0 + amount_1`

amount_0 should contain the number of labels in the y_train array that are equal to 0

number of labels in the y_train array that are equal to 1

we specify the weight of mistakes for a certain class below

`weight_0 = int(amount_1/total*100)`
`weight_1 = int(amount_0/total*100)`

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do that, probably most readable to use a list comprehension:

```
# transform each value to 1 if its the correct one and to 0 if not, then sum it up
amount_0 = sum([int(i==0) for i in y_train])
amount_1 = sum([int(i==1) for i in y_train])
```

or:

```
# filter values if they are the correct one into a list and check its length
amount_0 = len([i for i in y_train if i==0])
amount_1 = len([i for i in y_train if i==1])
```

or (this works if the values can **only** be exactly 0 or 1):

```
# 1s add 1 to the sum, 0s add 0, so sum(array) is the number of 1s, everything else is 0
amount_1 = sum(y_train)
amount_0 = len(y_train) - amount_1
```

This is all assuming you have a pure python list that holds the values, if you have something like a numpy array or a pandas series some of these approaches might not work and there are even shorter ways to do this.

Comment: `np.count_nonzero(y_train)` is much faster and more legible than a comprehension